# How to make a blank video with Moviepy

Tags: python, python-3.x, moviepy

How can I make a completely black video with no sound using moviepy? Preferrably with the size and duration of a base clip, eg 1280x720 and 5 seconds long at 30fps.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a a way:

```
from moviepy.editor import *

def color_clip(size, duration, fps=25, color=(0,0,0), output='color.mp4'):
    ColorClip(size, color, duration=duration).write_videofile(output, fps=fps)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    size = (200, 100)
    duration = 5
    color_clip(size, duration)
```

Comment: Thanks, this is really helpful.